# How to do custom action before session invalidation (time-out)?

Tags: session, session-timeout

I want to store some information of `current session's user` when a session is getting invalidated (**because of time out**). How can I do that?

> If this helps, I'm using Spring Security 3.1. So if there is any configuration in Spring I'm having no trouble understanding that.

There is a thing in Spring Security as `Session Expiration`. When a session expires, a filter catches it and I can have my desired information from it.

However the problem is when a session gets invalidated (**because of timeout**). Because, for the next `request` there will be a new `session` created and I'm not able to have access to the old one. **I want to know how I can customize `session invalidation` ?**